# SQL Query based on XML (list) input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

I have table like this:

**MYDATA**

```
Company Reference  FirstName  Surname
1         A001       Test1Name  Test1Surname
2         A001       Test2Name  Test2Surname
3         A001       Test3Name  Test3Surname
```

and xml variable `@searchList` that hold this data:

```
<list>
    <item>
        <company>1</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>2</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>3</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
</list>
```

Usually where there is just one condition I would do something like:

```
select * from dbo.MYDATA rec
    where Reference in
        (
            select entity.value('(reference/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') 
            from searchList.nodes('/list/item') as T(entity)
        )
```

Where there are 2 conditions (`company = xml.company and reference = xml.reference`) it gets more complex.

One way to do it is to create a temporary table with companyid and reference columns, insert everything from xml into that temporary table and do a join on the MYDATA table. Other way is a similar thing but with a subquery.

Is there any other more elegant and mostly important performance wise way to accomplish this?

---

### **UPDATE**

This is what gave me the best performance result for now:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT, Company INT,Reference VARCHAR(10),FirstName VARCHAR(100),Surname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1, 1,'A001','Test1Name','Test1Surname')
,(2, 2,'A001','Test2Name','Test2Surname')
,(3, 3,'A001','Test3Name','Test3Surname');

DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<list>
    <item>
        <company>1</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>2</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>3</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
</list>';

WITH SEARCHLIST (company, reference) as
(
    select li.value('(company/text())[1]', 'int') AS company
          ,li.value('(reference/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS reference
    from @xml.nodes('/list/item') AS A(li)
)

select rec.* from SEARCHLIST srl
    left join @tbl rec on srl.reference = rec.Reference and srl.company = rec.Company
where rec.Id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get a *derived table* out of your XML using `.nodes()`.

This allows you, to deal with the values taken from your XML as if they were a *normal* table:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Company INT,Reference VARCHAR(10),FirstName VARCHAR(100),Surname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'A001','Test1Name','Test1Surname')
,(2,'A001','Test2Name','Test2Surname')
,(3,'A001','Test3Name','Test3Surname');

DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<list>
    <item>
        <company>1</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>2</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>3</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
</list>';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT li.value(N'company[1]',N'int') AS company
          ,li.value(N'reference[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS reference
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/list/item') AS A(li)
)
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS t
INNER JOIN CTE ON t.Reference=CTE.reference --use any column however you like it
```

### UPDATE Performance

To be honest: You write *Other way is a similar thing but with a subquery.* The CTE approach is technically spoken quite the same as a sub-select in this case.

Depending on the size of your XML it is - in most cases - faster to use the XML method `.exist()` where you can check the existance of an `XPath` with predicates.

The CTE appraoch must read out the whole set, just to tear it down again. If performance matters, you can include a filter predicate in `.nodes()` too.

But the best solution is highly depending on your actual needs...

### UPDATE 2 working example with `.exist()`

Try this (changed the sample data to carry differing values)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Company INT,Reference VARCHAR(10),FirstName VARCHAR(100),Surname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'A001','Test1Name','Test1Surname')
,(2,'A002','Test2Name','Test2Surname')
,(3,'A004','Test3Name','Test3Surname'); <-- Will not be returned

DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<list>
    <item>
        <company>1</company>
        <reference>A001</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>2</company>
        <reference>A002</reference>
    </item>
    <item>
        <company>3</company>
        <reference>A003</reference>
    </item>
</list>';

select * from @tbl rec
where @xml.exist(N'/list/item/reference[text()=sql:column("Reference")]')=1
```

Comment: Yep, first one with CTE is what I ended up with...except I use this li.value(N'(company/text())[1]',N'int') instead of li.value(N'company[1]',N'int') which gives 50% performance improvement in reading xml values.

Comment: @HABJAN Great, I'm glad to read this! If my answer (helped you to) solve your issue, it would be nice to vote on it and accept it. Happy coding!